# Consulta de SQL: obtener registros que tienen los mismos valores en determinados atributos

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas y requiero obtener el nombre de los proyectos que los empleados "Pepe Pérez" y "Leonardo Martínez" tienen en común.

Las tablas son:

CREATE TABLE departamento (

```
dep_id int NOT NULL, 
dep_nombre char(45) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY ( dep_id )
```

);

CREATE TABLE empleado (

```
    emp_id int NOT NULL, 
    emp_nombre char(45) NOT NULL,
    emp_tipoContrato char(45) NOT NULL,
    emp_dep_id int NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ( emp_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( emp_dep_id ) references departamento ( dep_id )
```

);

CREATE TABLE proyecto (

```
    pro_id int NOT NULL, 
    pro_nombre char(45) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY ( pro_id )
```

);

CREATE TABLE empleado_proyecto (

```
    emp_id int NOT NULL,
    pro_id int NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY ( emp_id, pro_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( emp_id ) references empleado ( emp_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( pro_id ) references proyecto ( pro_id )
```

);

Los datos insertados son:

```
INSERT INTO departamento values
    (2001, 'Ciencias'),
    (2002, 'Mecánica'),
    (2003, 'Sistemas');

INSERT INTO empleado values 
    (1002, 'Pepe Pérez', 'Planta', 2001),
    (1003, 'Laura Gamboa', 'Temporal', 2002),
    (1004, 'Manuel casas', 'Temporal', 2002),
    (1005, 'Leonardo Martínez', 'Temporal', 2003),
    (1006, 'Camila Rojas', 'Planta', 2003),
    (1007, 'Andrés Cuervo', 'Temporal', 2001),
    (1008, 'Andrea Cuevas', 'Temporal', 2001),
    (1009, 'David López', 'Planta', 2002),
    (1010, 'Daniel Cao', 'Planta', 2002);

INSERT INTO proyecto values 
    (401, 'Brazo mecanico'),
    (402, 'Optimización de procesos'),
    (403, 'Automatización'),
    (404, 'Motores');

INSERT INTO empleado_proyecto values
    (1002, 401),
    (1002, 402),
    (1003, 401),
    (1004, 404),
    (1005, 402),
    (1005, 401),
    (1005, 403),
    (1006, 402),
    (1006, 401),
    (1007, 401),
    (1008, 402),
    (1009, 403),
    (1010, 403),
    (1010, 404);
```

La consulta que he planteado es la siguiente:

```
SELECT pro_nombre 
FROM empleado JOIN empleado_proyecto USING (emp_id) JOIN proyecto USING (pro_id)
WHERE (emp_nombre = 'Pepe Pérez' or emp_nombre = 'Leonardo Martínez' and pro_id = pro_id);
```

Sin embargo, no sé como obtener únicamente el nombre de los proyectos que ambos empleados tienen en común.

Comment: Serias tan amable de explicar que trataste de hacer con esa consulta? ademas de lo ambiguo, esto: emp_nombre = 'Pepe Pérez' or emp_nombre = 'Leonardo Martínez'  es imposible...

Comment: Por favor, mira el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Comment: sabes hacer un group by? solo hay que hacer un group by de una tabla ;)

Comment: ME parecia que era un ejercicio, por eso todas las preguntas. Podemos resolverte el ejercicio nosotros, pero no vas a estar aprendiendo nada de nada. Seria mejor que aprendas por vos mismo y sobre todo en base a lo que van viendo. Esto se soluciona con un group by (investiga como funciona eso), donde cuentes la cantidad de empleados

Comment: No conozco que es RelaX ni como funciona. Tu query en Sql se hace con un simple group by. investiga sobre eso... y la funcion count..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en la consulta que hiciste, lo que hice fue generar 2 consultas una que devuelve los proyectos de 'Pepe Pérez' y otra que devuelve los proyectos de 'Leonardo Martinez' basándose en los que encontró de 'Pepe Pérez'.

Me dió como resultado 2 proyectos:
 - Brazo mecanico
 - Optimización de
   procesos

```
SELECT DISTINCT pro_nombre
FROM empleado JOIN empleado_proyecto USING (emp_id) JOIN proyecto USING (pro_id)
WHERE emp_nombre = 'Leonardo Martínez' AND pro_nombre IN  (SELECT pro_nombre
                                                    FROM empleado JOIN empleado_proyecto USING (emp_id)
                                                        JOIN proyecto USING (pro_id)
                                                    WHERE (emp_nombre = 'Pepe Pérez'))
```

Comment: y que hace pro_id = pro_id?

Comment: es cierto, esa comparativa no es necesaria, ahora lo edito.

Comment: Otra cosa, la pregunta es sobre mysql. Esto anda en mysql?

Comment: Cierto en MySql no estoy seguro de si existe DISTINCT sin embargo hay algunas formas de emularlo, editaré mi respuesta para que funcione en MySQL

Comment: Ya que tu código cambio entonces considera por favor editar y quitar lo que habla de intersect

Comment: @gbianchi a mi me funcionó perfecto la solución de ryukazari. Pero como es eso que se soluciona fácilmente con un `group by`? Lo podrías mostrar?